# Create a variable with a "variable name" in php

Tags: php, class, variables, get

I want to create a points system with players.

I also want to give the user the possibility to add players so I first created an associative array called players that will stock the players and their scores, then I created a class named player, add the construct function,

And I'm stuck here:

in order to get all working, I need to create a new instance of players, and I'd like to know if it is possible to change the variable name using the GET method.

I mean, if I say that I want my new player to be named Omeyr, is there a way to create my variable as $Omeyr?

Thanks!

Comment: please post your code

Comment: You could always do something like `$var = 'Omeyr'; $$var = new Player();` - now you actually have variable `$Omeyr` - but what's the use?

Comment: Well, I didn't write the code on a computer yet. Only did some doodles on a sheet of paper

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the variable variables. It may be what you want :)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

It works like that :

```
$foo = 'bar';
$$foo = 'Hello!';

echo $bar;     // output : Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
${"Omeyr"} = "some string";
echo $Omeyr; //outputs "some string"

${"Omeyr"} = new Player(); //etc
```

Anyway, from what i understand, you definitely need a better approach to this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a specific variable for the player Omeyr, as you already have an array of all players. Omeyr will be the key for the player Omeyr in your players array.

eg.

```
$players['Omeyr'] = new player()
```

for acessing members later

```
$players['Omeyr'].score = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$$variable` to do it, but in this case I'm not sure at all whether it's the thing you really want to do.

Why is instantiating new objects of Player a problem for you?